# jquery script not working with jquery 1.11.0 cause of .live

Tags: jquery, function, live

I wrote this script but I know live function is deprecated in 1.11 version.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#menu-button').live('click', function(event) {        
            jQuery('#menumobile').toggleClass('hidemobilemenu');
    });
});
```

so it does not work, but I need jQuery 1.11 for other plugin.
I tried to adapt it with .on, but it did not succed.
As you can see it works in the snippet when you use jQuery 1.6.2 version
Any help is very welcome. Thanks

```js
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#menu-button').live('click', function(event) {        
   jQuery('#menumobile').toggleClass('hidemobilemenu');
    });
});
```

```css
#menu-button {
    background-color: #ddd;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
    z-index: 30;
}
#menumobile {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 50px 70px 0 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 29;
}
 .hidemobilemenu {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-button">
<a href="#"><span></span><span></span><span></span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="menumobile" class="hidemobilemenu">      
 <ul>
        <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php" ? "active" : "");?>"><a href="/index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/menu.php" ? "active" : "");?>"><a href="menu.php">MENU</a></li>
        <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/about.php" ? "active" : "");?>"><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/contact.php" ? "active" : "");?>"><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Change `.live` to `.on`

Comment: See [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page).

Comment: @DJDavid98 `.on` doesn't work in jQuery 1.6.2.

Comment: @DJDavid98 `bind()` is not a delegating method in 1.6 .. or current versions either

Comment: What problems are encountered getting rid of `1.6` and upgrading? Signature of `on()` to replace `live()` does not use same syntax

Comment: @charlietfl check my answer. I've updated the snippet. But stille the script with updated sintax does not work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily change .live with .on. The sintax changes.
I followed [this guide](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jun/12/Replacing-jQuerylive-with-jQueryon) but it still does not work.
Check the snippet. Dunno what's wrong

**EDIT**
SOlved. I just used the css for the child element, not the parent element, and now it works :)
snippet updated and working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-button").on("click", ".clickspan", function() {
    $("#menumobile").toggleClass("hidemobilemenu");
  });
});
```

```css
.clickspan {
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 13px;
  z-index: 30;
}
#menumobile {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 50px 70px 0 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 29;
}
.hidemobilemenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu-button">
  <div class="clickspan">
   <a href="#"> <span></span><span></span><span></span> </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="menumobile" class="hidemobilemenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == " /index.php " ? "active " : " ");?>"><a href="/index.php">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == " /menu.php " ? "active " : " ");?>"><a href="menu.php">MENU</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == " /about.php " ? "active " : " ");?>"><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == " /contact.php " ? "active " : " ");?>"><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```